# How to show $O_K$-rank of $M=(O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p)$-rank of $M$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.  Let $O_K, m_K$ are the ring of integers and maximal ideals of $K$ respectively. Consider the residue field $\mathbb{F}_p \cong O_K/m_K$, which is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra because there is a unique ring homomorphism $\xi:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{F}_p$ defined by $\xi(n)=n$ mod $p$.

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $O_K$-module. Also assume that $M$ is a module over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is $O_K$-rank of $M$ equal to $(O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p)$-rank of $M$ ?

Since $O_K$ is an integral domain, by definition, the $O_K$-rank of $M$  is the dimension of the $F$-vector space $(M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F)$, where $F$ is the fraction field of $O_K$ i.e., $F:=\text{Frac}(O_K)$.

i.e., $\text{rk}_{O_K}(M)=\text{dim}_F(M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F)$.

We have to show $\text{rk}_{O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{F}_p}(M)=\text{dim}_F(M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F)$.

Any help please

Comment: This is not true if $M$ can have torsion, even if $K = \mathbb{Q}$, e.g. take $M = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Is there a hypothesis on $M$ missing?

Comment: @hunter, ok, good. lets assume $M$ is torsion-free then.

Comment: Right I'll delete my comment, anyway OP's question is unclear, $\otimes_\Bbb{Z}$ doesn't assume any $O_K$ module structure.

Comment: A finitely generated torsion free $\Bbb{Z}$-module is a free $\Bbb{Z}$ module for which tensoring is obvious.

Comment: @reuns, I have assumed $M$ has module structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ as well. How do I show that $O_K$-linearly independent set  generating $M$  has $same~size$ to that of $(O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} O_K/m_K)$-linearly independent set generating $M$?